# PHP Date after time change in Europe

Tags: php, datetime

This morning I ran unit tests and they failed.
Tests took offers from last 48 hours by calculating time with:

```
date('U', time() - 48 * 3600)
```

When I used:

```
(new DateTime('-48 hours'))->format('U')
```

it shown one hour difference.

May the reason be that on sunday in Poland time was moved one hour backwards

Comment: Most probably! To avoid this kind of issue, use Epoch unix timestamp, and only convert for reading.

Comment: Using multiplication can expose issues when dealing with timezones that employ daylight savings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your server runs with `Europe/Warsaw` as default time zone. PHP date/time calculations are often incorrect if they cross DST boundaries, as it's the case here. I suggest you do all maths in UTC and convert from/to local time as needed.

Please compare:

```
$warsaw = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$start = new DateTime('2018-10-28 04:30:00', $warsaw);
$start->modify('-4 hours');
var_dump($start);

$start = new DateTime('2018-10-28 04:30:00', $warsaw);
$start->setTimezone($utc);
$start->modify('-4 hours');
$start->setTimezone($warsaw);
var_dump($start);
```

```
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-10-28 00:30:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Warsaw"
}
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-10-28 01:30:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Warsaw"
}
```

The Unix timestamp version of your code should be unaffected because a Unix timestamp is a fixed moment in time (thus doesn't switch with time zones).